# Order validation failed: personalDetails.gift: Cast to Boolean failed for value "No" at path "personalDetails.gift"

Tags: reactjs

I keep getting the error as stated in the title for my radio buttons.

This is how I declared my object variable. I used initialState and set objData to initialState. so i set form data to receive the values from the fields. where in this case the radio buttons are supposed to be boolean inside initialState, and now causing and error.

```
// creating order object
var initialState = {
  orders: [],
  personalDetails: {
    name: "",
    contactNo: "",
    email: "",
    address: "",
    gift: false
  },
  recipientDetails: {
    name: "",
    contactNo: "",
    email: "",
    address: "",
    message: ""
  },
  isDone: false,
  area: "",
  totalAmount: 12,
  deliveryFee: 5,
  remarks: ""
};

const [formData, setFormData] = useState(initialState)
var [objData] = useState(initialState)
const { personalDetails, orders, recipientDetails, isDone, area, totalAmount, deliveryFee, remarks} = formData

//inputting personal gift
const onChangePersonalGift = e => {
  const { name, value } = e.target;
  objData.personalDetails.gift = value;
  setFormData({
    ...formData,
    personalDetails: {
      ...formData.personalDetails,
      gift: value
    }
  });
};
```

And this is how I did up my radio buttons:

```
    <FormGroup tag="fieldset">
  <Label>
    <FontAwesomeIcon icon="gift" /> Gift?
  </Label>
  <FormGroup check>
    <Label check>
      <Input
        type="radio"
        id="giftYes"
        name="gift"
        onClick={toggleButton}
        value="Yes"
        onChange={e => onChangePersonalGift(e)}
      />{" "}
      Yes
    </Label>
  </FormGroup>
  <FormGroup check>
    <Label check>
      <Input
        type="radio"
        name="gift"
        value="No"
        onChange={e => onChangePersonalGift(e)}
      />{" "}
      No
    </Label>
  </FormGroup>
</FormGroup>
```

any idea what is causing the error or how can i rectify this?

Comment: What is "personalDetails.gift"? Can you provide a clearer output of the error? Is there a stacktrace or line number it is referencing? Have you a set of reproducible steps and a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example, and what the expected result/behavior should be?

Comment: personalDetail.gift is how i referrenced the gift field from inside the "personal details" object before pushing it in as an array. @DrewReese

Comment: What is `objData`? And all the other remaining questions? Is the line with `objData.personalDetails.gift = value;` the issue?

Comment: oh sorry, i missed out the part where i used objData. i added in to the question. not sure if it helps!! @DrewReese

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I duplicated the radio inputs in a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/billowing-wave-2nqq9?expanddevtools=1&fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js&theme=dark), so I can tell it's not anything in the code snippets you shared.

However, the error you reference is `Order validation failed: personalDetails.gift: Cast to Boolean failed for value “No” at path “personalDetails.gift”`  which leads me to believe you have some sort of form validation occurring and it is expecting the "gift" value to be (or castable to) a boolean. "Yes" and "No" are strings, and if castable to a boolean, are both truthy values. It would be better to set the values of the radio buttons to `true` and `false`, which would match your `initialState` data type for `personalDetails.gift: false` anyway.

```
<FormGroup check>
  <Label check>
    <Input
      type="radio"
      id="giftYes"
      name="gift"
      onClick={toggleButton}
      value={true} // <-- keeps the gift value a boolean
      onChange={onChangePersonalGift}
    />{" "}
    Yes
  </Label>
</FormGroup>
<FormGroup check>
  <Label check>
    <Input
      type="radio"
      id="giftNo"
      name="gift"
      value={false} // <-- keeps the gift value a boolean
      onChange={onChangePersonalGift}
    />{" "}
    No
  </Label>
</FormGroup>
```

*Note: You may need to adjust the validation logic if it too is trying to do anything fancy with the form values.*